# Navigating to a page in a frame, within a listbox

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have the following listbox on my page:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Name="SlideSelectorListBox" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSlide}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedSlideIndex}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Slides}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Padding="3" CornerRadius="5" Height="120" Width="200">
            <Viewbox IsEnabled="False">
               <Frame Height="656" Width="1360" Source ="{Binding Path=SlideURL}" IsEnabled="False"/>
            </Viewbox>
         </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I setup the listbox this way because I want to fill it with other pages along one side of my main page. I have gotten it to fill up with pages but I had to use

```
SlideURL = new Uri(pagePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

to navigate the frames as I add them to there pages. The problem is I can't send parameters to the pages when I navigate the frames this way. Anyone know a way to do this while being able to send parameters?

Comment: What parameters are you trying to send - querystring parameters, data context params?

Comment: please provide an example URI - where does the data for the "single string" come from? Is it static/dynamic, from a data binding, etc.?

Comment: The pages and parameters are stored in a SQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way that I found was to change the binding from the source of the frame to the content of the frame. Doh!

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Name="SlideSelectorListBox" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSlide}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedSlideIndex}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Slides}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Padding="3" CornerRadius="5" Height="120" Width="200">
                <Viewbox IsEnabled="False">
                    <Frame Height="656" Width="1360" Content="{Binding Path=SlidePage}" IsEnabled="False"/>
                </Viewbox>
           </Border>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Then you can make a collection of pages, passing the page parameters when you create it.

```
private Page _slidePage = new ProductionReportView(paramter);
public Page SlidePage
{
    get { return _slidePage; }
    set
    {
        _slidePage = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SlidePage");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`UriBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) to work with QueryString parameters. I would use a custom [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to convert the URI to a valid URI with parameters. Below is an example on how to create a basic string to URI builder. You could pass the parameter information to the converter using [`ConverterParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converterparameter.aspx) binding.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Converter from string to URI
/// </summary>
public class StringToUriConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Uri uri = null;
        string stringValue = value as string;
        if (stringValue != null)
            Uri.TryCreate(stringValue, UriKind.Absolute, out uri);
        return uri;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       throw new InvalidOperationException("Only one-way binding is supported!");
    }
}
```